# Remplazar caracteres javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito remplazar unos caracteres por otros en un input al vuelo y he pensado que con javascript lo puedo solucionar.

El tema es el siguiente:
 Tengo un input que lee códigos EAN13 y lo tengo preparado para que al insertar los números lo valide.

El caso es que ahora hay una pistola lectora de códigos de barras y al pinchar en el input y escanear un código en vez de escribir números escribe los símbolos que hay en esos números por ejemplo en el 6 el pone una & en el 5 un % y así con todos. Entonces necesito que al escribir los símbolos javascript los cambie a el numero que tiene asignada esa tecla para poder validarlo y que los humanos lo entendamos.

¿Se puede hacer esto con javascript? ¿cual seria la sintaxis?

Comment: Osea, dices que la maquina en vez de 10 puede retornar el simbolo de numero #?

Comment: te he dejado un ejemplo que soluciona el problema, sin embargo te sugiero que revises el manual de dicha pistola porque seguramente dicha funcionalidad debe poder ser configurada, Saludos!! ;))..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La mejor forma en como se pudiera hacer evitando [String.replace](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiMvdXf7r3TAhWHNiYKHa65DhsQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_replace.asp&usg=AFQjCNHkQtwO31hSFQouEf3GzduaYrfVmw&sig2=bu-R4ryH_p5dvKlLwCmG5A) y [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) seria creando un [diccionario](http://jrruiz.es/posts/javascript-diccionarios-o-arrays-asociativos/) manual y segun el caracter, cargas la letra correspondiente a la llave en el diccionario.

Ejemplo (también en [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yivotimago/edit?js,console)):

```js
var dic = {
  '&': '6',
  '%': '5',
  '#': '10',
  '(': 'N',
};

var resultadoLector = "(%#";
var resultadoHumano = "";
for (var i = 0; i < resultadoLector.length; i++) {
  resultadoHumano += dic[resultadoLector[i]];
}

console.log(resultadoHumano); //N510
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Quizás te conviene llevarlo a un input como pide en la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Dejo un ejemplo con replace() como alternativa a la respuesta anterior

```js
let input = document.getElementById('inputCode')

input.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  let code = this.value
  //Remplazar los valores
  code = code.replace('&','5')
  code = code.replace('%','6')
  // Convertir caracteres
  this.value = code
})
```

```html
<input id="inputCode" placeholder="Insert your code"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que entiendo la pistola de códigos de barra en vez de colocar los dígitos numéricos que están en el **teclado alfanumérico del 0 al 9** coloca los signos que están en dichas teclas.

De estar en lo correcto aquí te dejo un ejemplo de un `input` que al escribir los signos que están en las teclas del 0 al 9, estos los reemplaza por su contratarte numérico (es decir, hace caso omiso a la tecla **Shift**:

```js
//        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
signo = ["=","!",'"',"·","$","%","&","/","(",")"];
$(document).ready(function (){
 $("input").on("keydown",function (){
  n=signo.indexOf(event.key)
  if(n!=-1) {
   s=this.selectionStart;
   e=this.selectionEnd;
   a=this.value;
   this.value=a.substr(0,s)+n+a.substr(e)
   this.selectionStart=s+1;
   this.selectionEnd=e+1;
   return false
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Codigo:<input> (hace caso omiso a la tecla shift)
```

Por otro lado te sugiero que revises el manual de dicha pistola porque seguramente dicha funcionalidad debe poder ser configurada, Espero esto te sirva de ayuda, Saludos!! ;))..

Comment: Genial :) Funciona perfecto, mil graciiaaaas

Comment: Me complace verte ayudado, y recuerda calificar la respuesta que se apega mas a una solución al problema, Saludos!! ;))...